# Cropping/Clipping camera preview to just show top half of image

Tags: android, view, camera, crop

I'm developing an app that shows a camera preview on a SurfaceView but I only want to show the top half of the preview.

Is there a way of cropping/clipping the view or will I have to resort to obscuring the bottom half with something like an image,other view or drawing?

regards
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this method to do the cropping (basically using the clip child ability of an absolute layout to clip a surfaceview child)

```
    <AbsoluteLayout android:clipChildren="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="240dp" android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1" android:layout_height="80dp">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/swSurfaceView" android:layout_width="240dp" android:layout_height="160dp" android:visibility="visible"></SurfaceView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: This will only work on certain devices... on others it won't cause the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

Overlaying the `SurfaceView` with another view is the easiest way to do it... however, it's quite ugly if you ask me.

Why don't just set the `SurfaceView` height manually? Make it take the 50% of the screen space and it will do what you want. You don't provide code so we'll have to do some guesses: let's suppose you have a `LinearLayout`, then inside it you put two views: your surface view and another kind of view. Then, you set their height to be 0dip, and their weight to be 1... that should do it.

Comment: AFAICT that sort of method just "squashes" the preview :( - I'm looking to just display the upper half of the the preview, preferably in a "pretty" way :)

Comment: I've just tried what you suggested but it did as I suspected - it squashes the camera preview vertically so you just end up with a distorted view of the whole camera image rather than the top half of the image :(

Comment: Can you paste the code you have in your custom `SurfaceView`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I've posted the xml code I've ended up using :)